# Qt- QTextEdit's cursor

Tags: qt, cursor, qtextedit, qtextcursor

Is there anyway to use multiple cursor on QTextEdit?

```
QTextCursor cursor = text_edit->textCursor();
int curPo = cursor.position();
text_edit->setTextCursor(cursor);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to set multiple visible text cursors on a `QTextEdit`.

Comment: @afn Given that the editor itself has no knowledge of the cursors, my main question would be: what's the point of it? Perhaps you should expand your questions with some use cases and an explanation of why you're trying to do that.

Comment: I want something to show selection text in content.

Comment: @afn `QTextEdit` supports a single selection. Do you need something else? Perhaps a mockup screenshot would help.